# TypeError: $ is not a function - Javascript class containing a function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me crazy because this code use to work, now all of a sudden it's not working.. I've been trying to fix this bug for days, and when I googled my title, an exact query came up but it was no help. I was wondering if I paste my code you guys could help me figure out why I'm having this problem with "Firefox" only. Chrome works just fine fyi.

Here's my function:

```js
function getSections() {
    var sections = [];
    $('.sectionname').each(function() {
        var section = $(this).parentsUntil('ul.topics, ul.weeks').last().attr('id').match(/section-(\d+)/)[1];
        var name = $(this).text();
        sections.push({section:section, name:name});
    })(JQuery);
    return sections;
}
```

I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: You refer to `jQuery` as `JQuery` - is that deliberate?

Comment: (jQuery) does not help at the momment, same problem occurs

Comment: Did you namespace `jQuery` to `$`? (try replacing the `$` with `jQuery` and running your code)

Comment: Now it says jQuery is not a function haha : / @SethMcClaine

Comment: You do have jquery included right? (if you go to your console and type `$` and/or `jQuery` it says something like `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`

Answer (score 5):

You want `jQuery` not `JQuery` (note your use of capital `J`)

```
// your code
function getSections() {
  // ...
  $('.sectionname').each(function() { ... })(jQuery)
                                            ↑
                                            broken
}
```

Even if you fix `JQuery` to `jQuery`, you're still doing something wrong.

Really tho it looks like you're trying to do something like this

```
function getSections() {
    return $('.sectionname').map(function() {
        var section = $(this).parentsUntil('ul.topics, ul.weeks').last().attr('id').match(/section-(\d+)/)[1];
        var name = $(this).text();
        return {section:section, name:name};
    }).get();
}
```

The use of `.map` and `.get` is far more idiomatic. If you want to map the `jQuery` var to `$` in this function exclusively, you could do this

```
function getSections() {
  return (function($) {
    return $('.sectionname').map(function() {
      var section = $(this).parentsUntil('ul.topics, ul.weeks').last().attr('id').match(/section-(\d+)/)[1];
      var name = $(this).text();
      return {section:section, name:name};
    }).get();
  })(jQuery);
}
```

This way only the `jQuery` free variable will be accessed instead of `$`

More generally tho, people tend to use a single wrapper to do this instead of doing it once per function

```
// more commonly you'll see this
(function($) {
  // all of your jQuery code here
  // any use of $ will directly reference jQuery
  // ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Let me try that and will give you an update here in a second.

Comment: I'm still getting multiple errors for some reason. The getSections/<() is new after using your code and commenting out mine. @naomik TypeError: $ is not a function
getSections/<()
 concatjs.php:1191
getSections()
 concatjs.php:1190

Comment: Seems like your mixing JavaScript and PHP. Big mistake. Totally different problem tho.

Comment: you have no idea... I'm fixing code that I have not even created.. Don't worry about it I know ill figure it out one day by bashing my computer with a hammer. @naomik

Comment: I appreciate your help non-the less learned a few things from you. So thanks.. @naomik

Comment: You're very welcome. If you need help with the JS+PHP issue, you can post a new question. You're likely to get some constructive advice on the matter.